# Gather all possible combinations of 2 from a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list with 10 items in it. I am trying to output to console every possible pairing of 2. But it cannot pair with itself. For example
1,2
1,3
1,4 etc...

I found this to find all possible combinations within a list. Can someone help me modify it please?

```
    private static void GetCombination(IList list)
    {
        var count = Math.Pow(2, list.Count);
        for (var i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
        {
            var str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(list.Count, '0');
            for (var j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
            {
                if (str[j] == '1')
                {
                    Console.Write(list[j]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: use google look how easy it is to find a solution come on now.. [C# Bubble Sort](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/bubble-sort-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: I never said I didn't know what the code does that I posted. The code posted is to get ALL combinations from a list object. I am trying to get all combinations in pairings of X amount i.e. in pairings of 2 so the output would be.... 1,2 1,3, 1,10

Comment: your code originally would have given `var count = Math.Pow(2, list.Count);` a value of count to be `1024.0` which has nothing to do with anything close to what should be done without repeating values .. `FirstOne` gave you a starting point which needs 1 or 2 additions hopefully you can quickly figure out what needs to be added

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a list with 1 to 10, you need `1,2` `1,3` `1,4`...`1,10` - `2,1` `2,3`..`2,10` and so on.
You just have to use bubble and check if the first index is different from the second.

For more clarification, here is an example:

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>(new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 });
GetCombination(mylist);


private static void GetCombination(IList<int> values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < values.Count; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(values[i] + " " + values[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andy If you feel like you are stuck in something, try dividing the problem into steps and maybe even step by step. You can debug, if you will. Another tip is to figure out what you have to do regardless of programming language and only then, code. Anyway. if this is the answer you are looking for, don't forget to accept it and up vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a easy question.Adding to the answer of @FirstOne
you can also return the List containing all the combinations from the function:
List mylist = new List(new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 });
GetCombination(mylist);

```
    public static IList<Tuple<int,int>> GetCombination(IList<int> values)
    {
        List<Tuple<int,int>> _temp=new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < values.Count; j++)
            {
                if (i != j)
                {
                    _temp.Add(Tuple.Create(i, j));
                }
            }
        }
        return _temp;
    }
```